# Non-repeating, ordered combinations, finding whether they're divisible

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Imagine a list [1,2,3,4,5..] of range(1,1000000) and non-repeating ordered combinations where r=4 so: 1,2,3,4; 1,2,3,5...450,451,452,453 etc.

Except where r=30000.

It's not possible to generate all of these combinations. Provided a r length combination and knowing that the original list is 1-1000000 is it possible to find if the combination is at a position divisible by x?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What's wrong with $30,000$?

Comment: Each combination will include 30000 numbers in the way the example combinations contain 4. Given a random combination, in the example where r=4 this could be 4,5,6,400 I want to know if it's at a position in the list of combinations divisible by x. With an r of 30000 it's also not possible to calculate the absolute position based on the combination